# Relation of Force and Energy, from a biophysics point of view

Tags: forces, energy, biophysics

Considering us humans practically, does energy require force, ie we do apply some internal and external forces to do work, or does force require energy. ie we can only apply a force on an object if we have some energy?

Comment: Consider something on the ground. There is a gravitational force $F_g=mg$ due to the gravitational potential. This object has potential energy. Unless the object is moving, it doesn't "use" (convert) this potential energy and no work is done. What is the special point about humans applying force?

Answer (score 1):

Energy does not require force, as a moving object will have kinetic energy even if no force is acting on it. To give energy to an object is using work, so the second question is really asking if force requires work. The definition of work is the integral of the force function from the inital position to the final position. Even if there is a force, if the position doesn't change (which is posible if the *net* force is 0 N), then no work is done. Both of your propositions are therefore incorrect. I hope this helped answer your question.

Comment: The question is does applying force require energy? In most mechanical cases, force is created in some sort of potential, so you need this potential to exert force (you don't "use" this energy, no work is done).

Comment: @Timeless the special case here is as follows :
COnsider a first situation of any person who has to move a box. He must apply some force on the box. But if he is starved and has no chemical energy stored (ATP) then he will be unable to move the box. You, as a person must have some pre stored energy in you to apply a force.

Now, considering the reverse case also. When we do some work, we do apply a force. Therefore in the case of us humans, where there are multiple forms of interconvertible energy, is there a cyclic paradox between force and energy? Please dont consider the rigorous definition

Comment: @AyushBohra When you lie on the floor - even in a starved, energy-lacking state - you exert a force on the floor, namely your weight. This requires no energy consumption from you. A dead body still exerts this force. Clearly, some forces require energy to be produced (all those that need fuel, such as rocket thrust or the biomechanical push with your human hands), while other forces don't require any energy (such as weight, tension forces and normal forces).